# La grafia “scì” è corretta?

Tags: orthography

Ho notato in questi giorni che il correttore automatico del mio *smartphone* suggerisce con una certa insistenza “scì” al posto di “sci”, anche all'interno di parole composte (ad es. “portascì”). È una grafia più corretta? Non l'ho mai incontrata prima, ma dato che la mia maestra delle elementari pronunciava “sciare” senza lo iato ho poche certezze in campo di sport invernali.

Comment: Secondo me dovresti mandare una lettera di reclamo al produttore del tuo smartphone.

Comment: Pronunciare il verbo come ['ʃare] è terribile! Le *sciare* (pronuncia ['ʃare]) sono, in lingua siciliana, le colate di lava.

Comment: tempo fa vidi uno smartphone che correggeva `po' -> pò` :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sicuramente “sci” da solo si scrive senza accento, come puoi verificare in qualsiasi vocabolario (per esempio [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sci/)).

Invece “portascì” – come eventuali altri nomi composti del genere – richiede sicuramente l'accento grafico, perché in italiano lo vogliono tutte le parole tronche di più di una sillaba. È ben spiegato per esempio [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-grafico_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/):
«[l'accento tonico viene indicato graficamente] sulla vocale finale dei polisillabi tronchi (bontà, portò), anche quando sono composti da monosillabi che da soli non lo richiederebbero (trentatré, Oltrepò, nontiscordardimé)».

Comment: Non sono d'accordo sul "sicuramente", nel senso che è proprio una questione che suscita incertezze. Personalmente preferisco scrivere _portascì_ e _doposcì_ ma è un dato di fatto che la grafia più comune è proprio _portasci_ o _doposci_. Abitando a Pavia posso anche garantire che _Oltrepo_ è scritto molto spesso senza accento grafico anche in testi ufficiali. La concorrenza tra le due regole (accento obbligatorio sulle tronche _versus_ monosillabo componente non accentato) genera un esito molto controverso.

Comment: @MauroVanetti: Grazie per le segnalazioni. I testi ufficiali, purtroppo, non sono certo un'autorità in materia linguistica (vedi, per un esempio, tra i mille, [qui](http://cortmic.myblog.it/idegrado-linguistico-comune-padova/)). Se hai qualche riferimento bibliografico sulla regole concorrente (monosillabo componente non accentato), la aggiungo volentieri alla risposta. Quanto poi alla diffusione popolare di una grafia sull'altra, non vuol dire molto, perché spessissimo si vede scritto anche “lunedi”, “martedi” etc.

Comment: Mettiamola così: secondo Google, praticamente nessun libro in italiano scrive _portascì_. Prevale invece misteriosamente _doposcì_ su _doposci_. [ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=portasci%2Cportasc%C3%AC%2Cdoposci%2Cdoposc%C3%AC&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cportasci%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoposci%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoposc%C3%AC%3B%2Cc0 ] Siamo in uno di quei casi in cui anche un romanziere "ortograficamente consapevole" potrebbe scegliere _portasci_ senza sensi di colpa.